# Installing python packages in Namecheap CPanel (Python App)

Tags: python, pip, cpanel, namecheap, site-packages

I was trying to install a flask-based app on my website everything was fine, until i got this error when i was installing the library's with a requirements.txt:

error: subprocess-exited-with-error    × Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.  │ exit code: 1  ╰─> See above for output.    note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.error: subprocess-exited-with-error× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.│ exit code: 1╰─> See above for output.note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.

My requirements.txt

firebase

firebase_admin

Flask

Flask_Cors

pypdfium2

Pyrebase4

Werkzeug

I don't see why it doesn't work?, i tried to run it manually from the console but it just gave me another error

`[kazehoya@server145 flask-server]$ python server.py File "server.py", line 47 doc_ref = db.collection("admins").document(f"{admin.uid}") SyntaxError: invalid syntax [kazehoya@server145 flask-server]$` 
^

But this all works perfectly ran locally.
Okay, next problem.

Instead of using the pip install cpanel app feature, I wanted to try to manually install the packages.

I ran python -m pip install firebase

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/runpy.py", line 122, in _run_module_as_main
"**main**", fname, loader, pkg_name)
File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/runpy.py", line 34, in _run_code
exec code in run_globals
File "/home/kazehoya/newcorny.kazemo.shop/newcorny.kazemo.shop/flask-server/pip.py", line 29, in 
"This script does not work on Python {}.{}".format(*this_python),
ValueError: zero length field name in format

Update (Sep 5):
I got pip to work, but the same error occurs

Heres the image of the python app page :)
[image]
Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You can try to redo the requirements file. Run `pip3 freeze` or `pip freeze` and recopy it.

Comment: Well, as the error message says, a wheel fails to build. The first step would be to identify which package produces this error, and why. The portion of output you sent unfortunately doesn't include that info.